# High performance web+database server with MySQL, Sphinx, Nginx, PHP-FPM, Memcached and Redis

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, redis, sphinx

I've installed a web+database server, using the following (saw them on a tutorial) - I've combined them with Yii and it runs perfectly:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php5-memcached php5-mysql php5-redis redis-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client sphinxsearch
sudo pecl install -Z igbinary
```

Now I want to separate the web server from the database server. Can someone confirm, is this the right configuration?

---

**Web server:**

```
sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php5-memcached php5-mysql php5-redis redis-server mysql-client
sudo pecl install -Z igbinary
```

**Database server:**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 sphinxsearch
```

---

*I'm asking, since on many tutorials it says that Redis is actually a database caching server, but in this case, it seems that I'm using it only for PHP.*

Comment: `Redis is actually a database caching server`- Not necessarily and so is memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Redis is an in-memory database server.

Your configuration can be correct, it really depends on how your application is working and how you configure your connections.

Look at it this way: MySQL is also a database server, and you are also "only" using it through your PHP application, right? The same is true for Redis. The decision on where to put Redis is really up to you. You can put it on either server, as long as your application is configured to use the right one wherever it tries to speak with either MySQL and/or Redis.

However, it is kind of common to keep the Redis close to the application, as it is supposed to deliver results as fast as possible, and having it on the same server as your application can save you the TCP/IP overhead that talking to a different server would cause.

Comment: So basically, Redis can work with both PHP and MySQL, right? If so, I think my application is working using Redis only with PHP, so I won't install it on the database server. Thanks!

Comment: Redis can not work with MySQL, no. Not as far as I know at least. PHP can talk to Redis, and PHP can talk to MySQL. PHP is used for your application, and both Redis and MySQL are, lets say, "storages". Information is put in there and you can get it back from there again. They work in different ways, but they are both kind of a similar system.

Comment: Aah now I get it. Anyway, either way, there's no need to install it on the database server. Thanks for the help!